# Android accelerometer sensor returns zero

Tags: java, android, accelerometer

I am going to use accelerometer sensor in my app to read the phone orientation data. Most of the time I can read the data but sometimes the accelerometer just doesn't work.

Logcat produces the following message when the accelerometer fails:

```
W/SensorManager: ACCELEROMETER Sensor data was zero
```

Below is my code:

In onCreate():

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
magnetometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
```

In onResume():

```
sensorManager.registerListener(sensorListener, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
sensorManager.registerListener(sensorListener, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

In onPause():

```
sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorListener);
```

Listener:

```
private SensorEventListener sensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        float[] mGravity;
        float[] mGeomagnetic;

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
                mGravity = event.values;
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
                mGeomagnetic = event.values;
            if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
                float R[] = new float[9];
                float I[] = new float[9];
                boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
                if (success) {
                    float orientation[] = new float[3];
                    SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

        }
    };
```

Comment: You need to do event.values.clone();

Comment: @HoanNguyen What's the use of `clone()`? I can always read the values and do my own calculation, just fails at a low chance. Can this solve the stability problem? Thanks.

Comment: Your class members mGravity and mGeomagnetic references event.values which will be going out of scope once the method is done. Thus either mGravity or mGeomagnetic could point to any values if the memory is being reclaimed for something else.

Comment: Just put in the log for mGeomagnetic values and you will probably see that it will sometime change to a new value when it should not that is when event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER.

Comment: @HoanNguyen Thank you for your explanation. I've added the `clone()` to my code but time is needed to know if this solved my problem. Thanks!